# React Native FlatList Item with dynamic height and width

Tags: react-native, flexbox, flatlist

I have a screen in my design it will contain multiple images. Its looks like a gallery view. I need to display every item with **dynamic** width and height. please see the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design pattern is called **masonry grid layout**. There're many packages that make those layouts.

You can try this https://github.com/hyochan/react-native-masonry-list

Comment: Oh great, thanks @byiringiro-emmanuel